# Extract text from DIV on HTML jQuery POST response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm coding a website and decided to perform a jQuery POST to call a PHP function, everything worked but instead of only a DIV as a response I got a whole HTML page. My doubt is: how can I extract the text from the DIV I encapsulated it with the id "response"?

Here is the JS and PHP code:

```js
const showModal = (id) => {
        $.post("<?php echo SITE_URL;?>/index.php/crewdesk/getFlightInfo/"+id, (data) => {
            console.log(data)
        });
        $("#modalTitle").text(id);
        $("#bookModal").modal("show")
    }
```

```php
public static function getFlightInfo($id)
    {
        $condition = " AND s.id = '$id'";
        echo "<div id='response'>";
        echo json_encode(CrewDeskData::getFlights(self::$stats['location'], "$condition"));
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

And here is the console log of the response-> [image: Console output]

Comment: What framework are you using on the PHP side? You should only be returning the json_encode() line. Don't try to parse the response. Fix the PHP side to only return JSON.

Comment: I'm using Codon Framework I believe it was only used on PhpVMS. https://github.com/nabeelio/codon

Comment: I have not used either of these, but you should avoid returning HTML in the method if it's a JSON response. Also, if it's returning HTML in addition to what you have in the static method, then find out how to tell the framework that this should be a JSON response so that it just returns data from the method (ie: no header and footer HTML content so it's not an entire page being returned)

Answer (score 1):

Change you jQuery code to this below.

Using `$.ajax` which is similar to `$.post`

If you just want to return json data from your PHP file just use `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax` I am set to receive html as your echo a div only.

```
const showModal = (id) => {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo SITE_URL;?>/index.php/crewdesk/getFlightInfo/' + id,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        $("#modalTitle").text(id);
        $("#bookModal").modal("show")
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //handle error here
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Change your PHP code to this below

```
public static function getFlightInfo($id){
    $condition = " AND s.id = '$id'";
   echo "<div id='response'>".json_encode(CrewDeskData::getFlights(self::$stats['location'],"$condition"))."</div>";
}
```

Comment: I still run into the same problem. How can I get this text from the response?

![Console output](https://i.imgur.com/5l2WzRv.png)

Comment: @Braganca Its because your php file has STATIC HTML. offcourse it will return everything when you call it via `$a.ajax` if you need ONLY that data the `json_encode` one just put that PHP code in a separate PHP file. and then do ajax on that. I hope this make sense.